# How can I remove the previous owner's Google account in a pre-owned device?

Tags: samsung

i bought a used phone that has the old owner's information stored in Google Play. How do I erase it?

when I download games from Google play if they have already downloaded them they are showing up as the old owners how do I erase this to where the phone recognizes my account not their's for Google play?

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, you should factory reset the device, so you're starting afresh.

You haven't mentioned what device you have or what version of Android you're running, but usually the setting to factory restore a device is found within the main SETTINGS > BACKUP & RESET. Use the Factory reset option to erase all personal data from the device and start afresh. Once the device is rebooted, you'll be prompted to enter your Google account credentials and link your phone and all apps you download from the Play Store linked to your Google account.

Be warned, factory resetting your device will erase all personal data on the device. If there's any content, you want to retain, copy it over to your PC or to a cloud service like Google Drive or Dropbox (using your account, not the previous owner's).

Answer (score 0):

Go to main setting of phone and click on add account. Now add a new gmail account then you can remove the previous gmail account owner. Just tap on the owner account and there should be option to remove it.